# Using a selective @Entity

Tags: java, jpa, entity

I have searched StackOverflow for some time now, but have not been successful so far.
Thus creating this Question...

I am currently using JPA, but I have come across a problem (at least, for me it is). Here is the situation:
I have created a system in which a user can be removed, though not removed from the database (for the sake of holding on to the orders of this particular user). For this to work, I have simply added a boolean to the Entity User. All good so far, but here comes the tricky part. As the usage of the system does not require any 'removed' users, I do not want to retreive them from the Database.

Is there any way to add a statement of some kind to the @Entity annotation? Or shouldn't I be using @Entity at all, in this case?

Thanks in advance for the help!

PS. I am not looking for a solution in which I would have to create an User_OLD table of some kind.

Comment: Which JPA implementation do you use?

Comment: Not sure to understand... why can't you select only the users with the deleted flag = 0 ?? That's a simple db field, that is mapped as a boolean property in your @Entity User, and you can use this property for filtering items...

Comment: Well perissf, I was searching for a solution using an annotation, seems it is not possible though. I am now indeed trying to add this WHERE clause, but as I have stated at Melnik's answer, I am not sure whether my solution is correct.

Comment: @axtavt, I am using Eclipselink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I suggest renaming column "removed" to "inactive", because you do not remove user.

For retrieving entities, there are two choices here:

- Create USER_ACTIVE VIEW in database based on inactive == false and
  change your @Entity to use USER_ACTIVE view.
- Add WHERE inactive == false clause on retrieval from USER table.

If you have Entity, which holds Collection of Users, which is annotated with @FetchType.LAZY:

- Fetch users when needed with the same where clause as defined above.

Comment: I am trying to add a WHERE clause, no problem in that. Though, I have only managed to add this WHERE clause to a method findAll(). This would still mean that JPA would get all users by default, or doesn't it, due to lazy loading? Is it enough to edit only this method?

Comment: If your findAll() method (which would be findActive(), if you are retrieving only active users) queries entities with where clause on retrieval, then it is okay. What do you mean by LazyLoading?

Comment: Well, my question is, would JPA still retrieve all users outside of this method (by default), or would this event only be triggered by this method? Therefor I brought up lazy loading, but I'm pretty sure these users only will be retrieved when they are actually accessed?